# Why does the function inside onLoad not execute in my nextjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was learning nextjs on nextjs.org and did what I read on the tutorial but it doesn't work.
....why is the function inside onLoad not executing?
I have checked the networks tab in my browser's developer tools and there was no call made to that link.

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Script from 'next/script';
const FirstPost = () => {
  return ( 
<div>
    <Head>
    <title> BlogPost </title> 
    <Script 
    src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
    strategy = "lazyOnload"
    onLoad = {
      () => {
        console.log("script loaded successfully");
      }
    }
    /> 
   </Head> 
   <h3> first blog post in my next.js project </h3> 
   <Link href = "/"> <h2> Go home </h2></Link>
    </div>

  )
}

export default FirstPost;
```

Comment: Have you check your browser's inspection console. onLoad is executed at browser's side.

Comment: Yes I have, and my log was not there.

Comment: Things like this are fully invalid react, `< h2 >` - is that a typo or is that actually what your source code looks like? Have you looked in your server output for errors? Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them.

Comment: @AndyRay the editor messed it up here...my code is fine in my editor/ide.

Comment: Have you tried removing `strategy = "lazyOnload"`? I think it would be good for you to read more into the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script

Comment: I'm not sure if it's valid to put the `<Head>` tag inside a `<div>`, try putting the whole page inside a react fragment with `<>...</>` instead of a `<div>`.  Your code is also still invalid with things like `onLoad = {` with spaces around the `=`. When you say "no call made to that link." that means you could be looking at the wrong page, or you could be accidentally filtering network requests in Chrome's dev tools. I would also try with a vanilla `<script>` tag and see if that triggers a load.

Comment: @AndyRay I have tried doing all of that ... plus I already told you that my code is fine on my editor....stackoverflow's editor messed it up a bit. so don't bother about the syntax. I have used the regular <script> tag and still does not work. I have also inserted a vanilla <script> tag in my index.js file and the same thing happened. I think you can easily replicate this error.

Comment: @zhyp I have tried everything. I have tried all the options available for the 'strategy' property, removing it and also tried if it works with the vanilla <script> tag. All of them did not work. If you can, please replicate this error. Run this command --> npx create-next-app nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter"
import Head from next/head -- create a Head component -- add either a <Script /> tag or a <script> </script> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for bothering you guys...but my mistake was putting the `<Script/>` tag inside the `<Head></Head>` component.
These two options work fine...
putting the `<Script />` inside a vanilla `<head>` tag (using the vanilla `<head>`)OR
putting the `<Script />` tag outside the `<Head>` tag (when using the nextjs's version of Head)